# Javamelody and multiple app and jvm in same node

Tags: jvm, cluster-computing, wildfly-9, java-melody

we have 3 applications (app1/app2/app3) in cluster (server1/server2) with 2 jvms (8080/8180) in each node

for example

- http://server1:8080/app1,  http://server1:8080/app2,
  http://server1:8080/app3
- http://server1:8180/app1, http://server1:8180/app2,
  http://server1:8180/app3
- http://server2:8080/app1, http://server2:8080/app2,
  http://server2:8080/app3
- http://server2:8180/app1, http://server2:8180/app2,
  http://server2:8180/app3

We can't override the path to record datas, what it is possible in web.xml set app1/app2/app3 in storage path but on same server app1 on port 8080 and 8081 will save files to same folder

the -D option is not a valuable option, because we can specify by jvm specific parameters, but if we put

"-Djavamelody.storage-directory=/tmp/javamelody_my_instance" as ticket

## 692 in github mentionned

it will override app1 with app2 or app2 with app3 .... in each case it will cause issue

overwrite file is not good how we can monitor each app in each JVM ?

any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

The response i had in github was OK

in each node configuration:

-Djavamelody.storage-directory=C:\Windows\Temp\javamelody_[port_number]

i will have folders

javamelody_8080_app1, javamelody_8180_app1
javamelody_8080_app2, javamelody_8180_app2
javamelody_8080_app3, javamelody_8180_app3